# error about a node in C++

Tags: c++

I got this error and I dont know how to fix it.

```
error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'node' in this scope
            node *node = new node;
```

my code where the error is.

```
//New empty tree
struct node *newTreeNode(int data)
{
    //New tree nodes
    node *node = new node;
    //New data node
    node->data = data;
    //New left node
    node->left = nullptr;
    //New right node
    node->right = nullptr;

    return node;
}
                             ^
```

Comment: And, presumably, `struct node *node`.  And also not to name variables the same as types.

Comment: @TripeHound: No, `node* node` is "fine".

Comment: I think you mixed up c and c++. In c++, the key word `struct` is just like `class`. So we don't need to add `struct` before `node`.

Comment: @Thomas: Ironically the problem here is that he _does_.

Answer (score 6):

This error comes from the strangeness that is declaring an object with the same name as its type:

```
node *node = new node;
```

Not only is this extremely confusing to readers of your program, but now on the RHS the word `node` means the object, not the type. So `new node` becomes invalid.

The error message is kindly informing you that you can make `node` refer to the *type* by writing `struct` before it:

```
node* node = new struct node;
```

This works because, when `T` is a class type, `struct T` always means that class type `T` and cannot mean anything else.

But, honestly, *simply do not do this*. Use better names.

Answer (score 5):

You have declared a variable called `node`. That is the name of a type you're intending to use after that declaration. So you need to specify that you're referring to the type, not the variable by using `struct` or `class` appropriately.

```
node *node = new struct node;
                 ^^^^^^
```

The better solution would be to use a different name for the variable.

```
node* n = new node;
```